# logical difference between flex: none and flex: 0 0 100% for mobile

Tags: css, flexbox

the visual view of the tile is the same as for all tile, but I would like to know which will be logically correct to set 100% of tile width using flexbox property. where the flex: none or flex: 0 0 100%, because as per the bootstrap4 grid system they used flex: 0 0 100%;

```css
img {
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex div {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 299px;
}

.auto {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.hund {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.none {
  flex: none;
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex div {
    flex: 0 0 33.3333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333%;
    
  } 
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="auto">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x230"> This is flex-basis auto
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="hund">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x230"> This is flex-basis hund
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="none">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x230"> This is flex-basis none
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="pointless"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x230"> This is flex-basis pointless
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the `max-width` for `flex div` and check it out... `flex: none` and `flex: 0 0 auto` are the same thing, it allows the *flex items* to take as much width as its content...

Comment: @kukkuz thankyou. I would like to know the difference between flex: none and flex: 0 0 100%

Comment: `flex: none` means the *flex item* is not stretched / shrinked, it would take as much space along the *flex direction* as its contents (because `flex-basis` is *auto* here)... In the case of `flex: 0 0 100%`, `flex-basis` is 100% which means each flex-item will always take up the full space available along the *flex direction*.

Comment: @kukkuz thankyou bro.